# How can I get all the controls in a namespace?

Tags: c#, namespaces, controls

How can I get all the controls in a namespace? For example, I want to get the controls in System.Windows.Forms: TextBox, ComboBox etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558127/how-can-i-get-all-controls-from-a-form-including-controls-in-any-container

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949246/how-to-get-all-classes-within-namespace

Comment: @Gunner, please read the question, he is talking about namespace not the form container in the link you specified.

Comment: @Akash : please check the history - the title was changed from 'in a control' to 'in a namespace' it was quite an ambiguous question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The notion of a *control in a namespace* is a bit unclear. You could use reflection to get classes in an assembly in a given namespace which derive from a particular base type. For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var controlType = typeof(Control);
        var controls = controlType
            .Assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => controlType.IsAssignableFrom(t) && 
                        t.Namespace == "System.Windows.Forms"
            );
        foreach (var control in controls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(control);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder whether you need to do a 'startswith' rather than equality in the namespace comparison so that controls in child namespaces are included.

Comment: @Nick, yes this is a possibility and it will depend on the specific requirements.

Comment: Genius. With this I can even get all controls from a custom namespace from my app. Just what I've searched for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

this will return all classes in a specified namespace :

```
string @namespace = "System.Windows.Forms";

var items = (from t in Assembly.Load("System.Windows.Forms").GetTypes()
        where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == @namespace
        && t.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Control))
        select t).ToList();
```

Comment: Also you need to check that the class is a control.

Comment: @Nick sure, Edited to check the control type! ;)

Comment: can not find System.Windows.Forms

Answer (score 0):

Your form object has a `Controls` member, which is of type `ControlCollection`.  It is essentially a list (with some other interfaces under the hood) of all of the controls.

EDIT: As per your comment, you need to cast the control back into a textbox.  First you must identify it as a control.

```
foreach (var control in controls)
{
    if(control is TextBox)
    {
        (control as TextBox).Text = "Or whatever you need to do";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can i create a control from a string value ?

Comment: "System.Window.Forms.TextBox" how can i create a textbox from this string value