# Looping through labels with similar name C#

Tags: c#, forms, label

I want to change the background of some labels depending on what is written on a text file:

```
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] words = new string[7];
            StreamReader read = new StreamReader(path);
            while(!read.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = read.ReadLine();
                words = line.Split(';');
                if(words[6] == "no") 
                {
                    //-----What I have to write here---
                }              
            }
            read.Close();
        }
```

There are over 50 labels named "lbl101","lbl102","....","lbl150"

Comment: I think its not clear what your asking. On what condition you want to wich label ?

Comment: put all of them on a stack and change its color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the working solution:

```
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int count = 101;
            string[] words = new string[7];
            StreamReader read = new StreamReader(pathRooms);
            while(!read.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = read.ReadLine();
                words = line.Split(';');
                if (words[6] == "no")
                {

                        Label currentLabel = (Label)this.Controls.Find("lbl" + count, true)[0];
                        currentLabel.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

                }
                count = count + 1;
            }
            read.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
if(words[6] == "no") 
{
    int count = 150;
    for (int a = 1 ; a < count; a++)
    {
        Label currentLabel = (Label)this.Controls.Find("lbl"+a,true)[0];    
        //change color of currentLabel
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it cannot convert type System.Windows.Form.Controls[] to System.Windows.Form.Label

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate all over them using `OfType<T>()` method on `Controls` collection of form like:

```
if(words[6] == "no") 
{
    foreach(var label in this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(x=>x.Name.Contains("lbl")))
    {
         label.Text = "Some Text";
    }
}
```

This will only work on the labels that are direct child of form, labels nested inside other user controls or nested panels will not be affected, for that [you have to do it recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1558145/1875256).

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the Controls collection of the form checking for Label objects. Then, amend accordingly as per the specified value.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Create a List with all the labels.

```
Label lbl101 = new Label();
Label lbl102 = new Label();
...

List<Label> labels = new List<Label>()
{
    lbl101,
    lbl102
...
};
```

2.) If your words[] string is the name of the color you can write:

```
if(words[6] == "no") 
{
   System.Drawing.Color myColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(words[..]);
   foreach(Label l in Labels)
   {
       l.BackColor = myColor;
   }
}
```